# Memory overwriting other memory issue in Numba?

Tags: python, list, memory, numba

Take the following script:

```
import numba

@numba.njit
def foo():
  lst1 = [[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10]]

  for i in range(300):
    lst2 = []
    lst2.append(1)

    del lst1[1]
    del lst1[0]

    lst1.append([1,2,3,4,5])
    lst1.append([6,7,8,9,10])

    if len(lst2) > 1:
      print("This should never print!")
      print("Length of lst2(should not ever be greater than 1): ", len(lst2))

for i in range(200):
  foo()
```

If you run this, you will get that sometimes the prints happen even though they shouldn't. 'lst2' should never have length more than 1 since it only gets appended to once and then reset in each iteration. It seems that appending to lst1 is somehow "interfering" with lst2. My suspicion is some kind of memory problem where 'lst1' appending is overwriting other memory? But I am not sure.. When I run this, the length of lst2 somehow ends up being 5 sometimes which is super weird.. Thank you for the help!

Comment: It looks like a bug of Numba. I strongly advise you to report it on the bug tracker unless it is already reported by someone else. See : https://github.com/numba/numba/issues . I guess there is a buffer overflow in the code generated by Numba.

Comment: Yeah I have made a report here already: https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/8753